Voxel Memory Management
I have a query about voxel memory management, I wonder what is the most efficient way, considering the size, to store chunks on disk.
My current engine generates a chunk size of 32^3, and I've built in a compression algorithm that packets the data into a single byte if feasible. Each chunk is the made up in layers, giving the algorithm efficient space to work.
I heard on how Minecraft stores their chunks using the new Advil format. It's quite simple actually. Chunk is store with all data, next a list of entity positions and properties follow. Compression, is of course, probably before dumping data happens, but don't need to achieve that because my chunks compress almost to a single byte.
The point I'm trying to address is that how do I go about saving chunks in a region size of 8^3 of chunks efficient? Like I've thought of some ways for dumping data into a buffer, than saving the massive buffer on file with the metadata as the region headers. I don't know, just wondering if this is a practical idea.
Like I've thought of some ways for dumping data into a buffer, than saving the massive buffer on file with the metadata as the region headers. I don't know, just wondering if this is a practical idea.
